# When does pressing the Enter (Return) key matter when creating a regex matching expression?

Tags: r, regex, grepl

I want to search for multiple codes appearing in a cell. There are so many codes that I'd like to write parts of the code in succeeding lines. For example, let's say I am looking for "^a11","^b12", "^c67$" or "^d13[[:blank:]]". I am using:

```
^a11|^b12|^c67$|^d13[[:blank:]]
```

This seems to work. Now, I tried:

```
^a11|^b12|  
^c67$|^d13[[:blank:]]
```

That also seemed to work. However when I tried:

```
^a11|^b12|^c67$|  
^d13[[:blank:]]
```

It did not count the last one.

Note that my code is wrapped into a function. So the above is an argument that I feed the function. I'm thinking that's the problem, but I still don't know why one truncation works while the other does not.

Comment: use backticks to write inline code, four spaces to write code blocks

Comment: This is a good question, but would be greatly improved if you included actual R code, including quotes around your patterns and a sample string to search.

Comment: thanks. Unfortunately, I can't disclose the actual R code. The function does seem to be counting properly, I just don't get why it doesn't do so in some breaks but not in others.

Comment: We don't need your "actual code" and test string, just an example with two or three cases to that we can run and test, along with the command (maybe `grepl`?) that you're using so that there's no ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

I realized the answer today. The problem is that since I am feeding the regex argument, it will count the next line in the succeeding code.

Thus, the code below was only "working" because ^c67$ is empty.

```
^a11|^b12|  
^c67$|^d13[[:blank:]]
```

And the code below was not working because ^d13 is not empty but also this setup looks for (next line)^d13[[:blank:]]  instead of just ^d13[[:blank:]]

```
^a11|^b12|^c67$|  
^d13[[:blank:]]
```

So an inelegant fix is:

```
^a11|^b12|^c67$|  
^nothinghere|^d13[[:blank:]]
```

This inserts a burner code that is empty which is affected by the line break.

Comment: A more robust fix might to be define the pattern segments as separate strings of reasonably size and `paste0()` them together.